# Using a Django project and static files in a subfolder of root

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I recently deployed a Django project to my DigitalOcean Droplet. I need to access it in a subfolder of root (i.e. www.domainname.com/). So far this works using the WSGI Aliasing in the apache config files. I am having trouble serving static js files though.

I am using the {% static %} tag in templates to do this. However my js files seem to always be replaced by the current page's html when I inspect them in the browser. Here are my static related settings in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/<project name>/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static"),
]
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here's my apache configuiration:

In sites-available/default:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost <project name>:8000>
    ServerName <project name>
    ServerAlias <domain>/<project name>
    ServerAdmin <email>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/<project name>
    WSGIScriptAlias /<project name>/ /var/www/html/<project name>/<project name>/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/logs/custom.log combined
    WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/<project name>
</VirtualHost>
```

In apache2.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /<project name> /var/www/html/<project name>/<project name>/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/<project name>

<Directory /var/www/html/<project name>>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

**UPDATE 2**

It appears the .js files are being requested by appending the static path to the path of the current page, i.e.

```
<domain name>.com/<project name>/<app name>/<page>/<project name>/static/js/<js file name>
```

Comment: You'll need to show your Apache configuration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an [`Alias` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) in your Apache configuration so your static files are served.

Unlike templates, which are rendered through Django views prior to being served, static files are generally served directly by the web server (or some separate service) for performance. After all you generally only want the file itself, so the overhead Django requires is unnecessary. This is discussed in Django's documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Without the `Alias` directive, the request is passed to Django for handling. Django changes the default behavior of Apache from serving files from `DocumentRoot` directly, to mapping URLs to views which then construct the response. So, depending on your `urls.py` arrangement, the static file request might result in a 404 page or a response (the HTML you're seeing) from a matching view.

To solve this, you can add

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/<project name>/static/
```

to your virtual host in your configuration file. This will tell Apache to serve files from your static directory when a request is made at a URI beginning with `/static/`.

For example, a URI of `/static/index.js` will cause Apache to serve the file `/var/www/html/<project name>/static/index.js` as a response.

---

Additionally you have an error in your `VirtualHost`. The address you're providing it is `<project name>`, which is not a valid option ([see here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost)). The virtual host address must be either an IP address, domain name, or the wildcard `*`.

Since `<project name>` is none of these, the virtual host is not matched to the anything, and the configuration within it is not applied. I would suggest fixing it by changing

```
<VirtualHost <project name>:8000>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
```

which will instead match on any host expected by the request.

Comment: I'm afraid after adding that line to my virtual host config, I still experience the same problem. I can inspect where the files are apparently linked to from Chrome and evidently the static path gets appended to the current  page. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: There are three ways you can link a url with each having a different effect. The first (example.com/static/) routes to the specified url, the second has a leading slash(/static/) and routes to the specified url relative to the current domain, and the third without a leading slash (static/) which routes to the current url with the specified url appended. So, how are you linking the file? It should only be `src="{% static 'js/myscript.js' %}"`, however your url appears to have `<project name>` prepending that.

Comment: To be clear, the appending is only half the problem now. Even if you add a leading slash `/<project name>/static/js/myscript.js` won't lead to the correct resource, as Apache is aliasing `/static/`. If you want `<project name>` before `static` in your static file urls, the alias needs to be `Alias /<project name>/static/ /var/...`.

Comment: I have changed the alias to /<project name>/static/ and restarted the apache server but now I just get a 404 error. It seems to be requesting the js files from <domain name>.com/static/jsfile.js rather than <domain name>.com/<project name>/static/jsfile.js now.

Comment: My source is just `{% static 'js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' %}`.

Comment: I'm afraid that is still not working. It's still trying to find the static files at `<domain name>.com/static/jsfile.js`.

Comment: This is the line copied from the `default` file in sites-available: `Alias /static/ /var/www/html/<project name>/static/
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134614/discussion-between-yummies-and-youssef-sami).